# How to get mean, stdev, min, max output from a python dataframe to an excel file?

Tags: python, excel, pandas

I have an existing dataframe that my script has created. At the end of the script I convert it to  a .xlsx file using pandas. I have been able to do some simple formatting tasks like enlarging the column sizes from the python script.

I would like to know how to get the mean (and others but once I figure out one of them the others should follow easily) from a number of the columns in the dataframe/excel file and I want them to be displayed at the bottom of the excel file. It would look something like this:

```
| ID | Drag Factor | Implulse | MFR |
  1         23           8       4
  2        657           10      6  
  3        300           17      8


MEAN:   326.666    |    11.6  |  6
```

I did not add much of my code because I am really just looking for direction to any modules in panda or xlsxwriter that may accomplish this task. But if you would like me to be more specific just comment and I will edit the post to include my exact script. Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Calculate mean and other parameters by applying python commands on your dataframe before converting into excel. Use command `df.mean()` (modify it according to your needs, everything related to it is available on Google) Store those values in a variable and after converting your dataframe into an excel sheet use `sheet1.write(cell row, cell column , value)`

Comment: Okay so my dataframe changes with each entry. I know that the cell column is always going to stay the same but I don't always know where the bottom cell row is going to be. If there are 5 entries I would want this mean data on row 6 but if there are 10 entries I would want it on row 11. How could I achieve this? Your answer otherwise works!

Comment: Try number of rows in your dataframe, and in .write() command, put in number of rows+1. number_of_rows = len(df.index), sheet1.write(number-of_rows+1, cell column , value)

Answer (score 2):

You could do something like this. Create a dataframe that gets the mean of all columns with  `df.mean()`. This summarizes the data horizontally rather than vertically, so then with `.T`, you can transpose the data. Then, append it back to the dataframe using `.iloc` to do some manipulation of the data to get in the format you want:

```
df1 = df.mean().reset_index().T
df1.columns = df1.iloc[0]
df1.iloc[1,0] = 'Mean'
df2 = df.append(df1).reset_index(drop=True)
df2.iloc[-2] = ''
df2.to_csv('df2.csv', index=False)
```

output:

```
ID   Drag Factor    Implulse    MFR
1    23             8           4
2    657            10          6
3    300            17          8

Mean 326.667        11.6667     6
```

So, the output includes a space between the data and summary data.

Comment: Would this method still work if some of my columns outputs are strings? I would obviously not want these in my calculations so is there a way to skip over the columns that I do not wish to compute .mean() on?

Comment: @newtopython , yes it will! When the data appends, it will show up as `NaN` for strings. If you want to clean that data up further you can do `df=df.replace(np.nan,'')` on the whole dataframe or `df['your_string_col`] = df['your_string_col`].replace(np.nan,'')` on just the column.

Answer (score 0):

try to use **df.describe()**

count    9.000000
mean     5.111111
std      2.147350
min      1.000000
25%      4.000000
50%      6.000000
75%      6.000000
max      8.000000
dtype: float64

Comment: Hey I see that you are a new contributor! I cannot really understand your answer. You should look at the other two answers on this post to get an idea of how to write your answers clearly.